# Why is my distinct NOT working? SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select distinct(caa.account_name), count(ool.ordered_item), caa.account_number
from oe_order_lines_all ool, hz_cust_accounts_all caa, oe_order_headers_all hdr
where trunc(hdr.creation_date) between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31'
and hdr.orig_sys_document_ref = ool.orig_sys_document_ref
and caa.cust_account_id = ool.sold_to_org_id
group by caa.account_name, ool.ordered_item, caa.account_number
order by count(ool.ordered_item) desc
```

I am trying to find which account name orders the most ordered item. 
When I run this, it returns values but does not distinct account names. It will give Amazon 155, Amazon 200 instead of one value (Amazon 355).  Any suggestions?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function.  You are just confusing yourself by using parentheses around the first expression in the `select`.

Comment: That is not how distinct works; if you want the count per account_name, why are you grouping on order_item and account_number?

Comment: Oh! I thought I could use it like a function. Thank you so much for correcting me. I am new to this so the advice is great.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use different columns while placing distinct for account_name:

```
select distinct
    caa.account_name
from
    oe_order_lines_all ool,
    hz_cust_accounts_all caa,
    oe_order_headers_all hdr
where
    trunc(hdr.creation_date) between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31' and hdr.orig_sys_document_ref = ool.orig_sys_document_ref and caa.cust_account_id = ool.sold_to_org_id
group by caa.account_name , ool.ordered_item , caa.account_number
order by count(ool.ordered_item) desc
```

Comment: Thank you, I now know I cannot use distinct as a function or in (). However, your code will not work. Putting the count(ool.ordered_item) in the order by will not count the items. Also, the distinct is still not working.

Comment: yes you must remove the group by and keep the only group_name in group by

Answer (score 1):

Does:

```
select caa.account_name, count(ool.ordered_item)
from oe_order_lines_all ool, hz_cust_accounts_all caa, oe_order_headers_all hdr
where trunc(hdr.creation_date) between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31'
and hdr.orig_sys_document_ref = ool.orig_sys_document_ref
and caa.cust_account_id = ool.sold_to_org_id
group by caa.account_name
order by count(ool.ordered_item) desc
```

give you want you wanted?

Comment: For some reason when using count() I have to group by all columns? I am unsure how this works but I always get errors when not adding all columns in my group by.

Comment: Yes, any time you use an aggregate function like count() or sum() you have to group by all other columns.  This is because aggregates are group the results inherently, so you have to group the other columns to match the total rowcount.

Comment: Ex: A table with two columns, fruit and quantity.  Say you have two types of fruits, apples and oranges.  If you select * the table you will return 10 rows.  If you select sum(qty), fruit you will return 2 rows.  The two won't work unless you tell SQL to group fruits down to the 2 unique rows as well.